# Is it grammatically correct and natural to use 'in where' in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is the use of 'in where' correct and natural in the following sentence?

> In where I live, people usually eat with their bare hands. (This is not the case. Just an example sentence.)

Comment: Asked for this: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67389/why-does-this-kind-of-places-often-appear-in-anime

Comment: @BCLC: "In the area where I live, there are no such places at all. Why is this kind of place so common in anime?"

Comment: "Where I live" or "In here, where I live" or "In XYZ, where I live" sounds more natural.

Comment: @banuyayi - "In here, where I live" would, probably, refer to a room, or building, or cave (and even then it sounds a bit unusual, unless referring to things inside the room/building/cave/etc.)... "Here, in London, where I live..." would be used for a city/town/etc..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. That's neither correct nor natural. We would probably say,

> "Where I live, people usually eat with their bare hands."

You might be thinking of *in which*. In formal English we might say,

"The town in which I was born had no hospital."

But generally we say, "The town where I was born..." or, informally, "The town I was born in..."

Comment: *"In the town where I was born..."* also works if you modify the rest of that sentence a bit - e.g. the first line of the Beatles' *Yellow Submarine*.  For this example: *"In the town where I was born, there was no hospital."*

Answer (score 3):

"Where" already incorporates the "in" meaning, so there is no need to repeat it.

You need either "where I live, people usually eat with their bare hands." or "In the (place or something) where I live, people usually eat with their bare hands."